# What should the "gateway" tag be used for?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tags

We have a tag called [gateway](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gateway). Perhaps with insufficient forethought, I am partially responsible for its existence. (I used it to indicate the personal computer brand.)

Should [gateway](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gateway) be used for computer branded "Gateway"? Or should it be used for network gateways, like routers (as its current tag wiki says)?

Or should it not exist, due to this ambiguity?

Or should it be used for both? (That seems like a bad idea to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since I initiated the original edit, it didn't occur to me that it also could be Gateway Computer Company.  But since this is about Ubuntu, it doesn't make a lot of since to be about the Company, and that it should be about network gateway.

Based on Eliah Kagan comment below, and as per Bruno Pereira, computer gateway should be merged with the network tag, and the tag gateway should be about the company.

Comment: I do think there's merit to the idea that we don't need a Gateway brand tag, as Bruno Pereira [says](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/3752/22949). But please note that we have many other brand tags, like dell, hp, compaq, ibm, and so forth, and most of those are quite useful.

Answer (score 6):

Gateway as a computer brand is so irrelevant that I do not see a reason why it should exist. Add that the fact that *gateway* as network gateway should be covered by [network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/network) and that makes the complete tag sort off useless, totally, imo.

Tags should have meaning, base, posts to sort. Gateway as a brand has such a small market share (were they bought by Dell or something?) that little or no questions arrive specifically about Gateway computers and a gateway tag makes no sense alone, no one asks "I have a problem with my gateway" normally you will see "Problem with wireless" or "Internet" or "Network", if its about gateways or not comes later on with some troubleshooting.

Comment: A [search for gateway](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=gateway) reveals that we have a very large number of questions about the Gateway brand. Some are about network gateways, but at least as many if not more seem to be about Gateway brand hardware.

Comment: Then there is no discussion here, if you are really going to use Gateway as a tag then it should be the brand, not the network topology aspect of networking.